Disable Wordpress Redirect URL child to another link if not exist
One of WP feature is to redirect any page url child slug to a similar page with same slug name if a page with that slug not exist.
For example:
domain.com/what-ever-you-write/about (Not exist and should show 404 page)
but actually redirected to
domain.com/about
How to stop this feature, Because I want to show 404 page instead of redirection.
I had tried the "template_redirect" hook but it was not working because it was running after redirection.

WordPress has a default hook for template_redirect that calls redirect_canonical(). Sadly, besides canonicalization, it also attempt to "fix" 404s. The simple fix is to just remove the redirect, however you can also conditionally remove it, too, if you want to focus to only a subset of URLs. I usually recommend the latter.
